# improve and simplify css with php parser

Tags: php, css, parsing, simplification

I want to improve css syntax in several ways such as:

- defining variables
   `link-color1 = #fff`
- mathematical computing
   `width:500-3-2` *this seemy stupid but with variables:*
    `width: container - inner - 3px;`
- style extending
    `#foo{background:#ddd;color:#eee;} #bar {@extend: #foo;color:#fff;}`
- cross-browser features
    `-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;` replace to
  `border-radius:3px;`

*these are only examples, my ideas, but the library can be different*

I am looking for a php library which **parses** a file which sytax is similar to css, and generates a valid css document.

This is important that **I dont want to insert php sytax into my css** file because:

- PHP looks complicated and ugly
  `#foo {color:<?php echo $color1; ?>;}`
- Notepad++ gets absolutely confused. *Me too*

---

**[SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) is very good solution for offline work**, but i still search for PHP solution because:

- The improved css files would be available for the other developers so they can modify and test it. For a larger community php-parser used on the server is an **easier** way.
- PHP can also be resource sparing with a simple revision system based on file modification date and hashcodes.

---

Here is an **example** what i wrote:
[php parser](http://pastebin.com/k7tGhL2y) at `/css/index.php`

usage:

```
@color1: #1a1a1a;
@color2: #444444;

div#container {background:@color1;}
div#inner {background:@color2;}
```

the HTML link:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/?main.css" />`

This works only with colors. I need a parser for the listed options.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'defining variables' and 'style inheriting'? Do you want to have a PHP variable with a color value so that you can use it for more than one CSS property?

Comment: `I need a php file which parse my improved` a php that parses your css? I don't get what you mean. To parse it you can just use the php variables without having to create a custom parser

Comment: This link might be of interest. http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#css_expressions

Comment: no. i have seen a library which does it exactly what i need, but i forgot the name of this. so it exists. i hope somebody knows this name, or a similar

Comment: I don't really see the point of the inheriting, as you can just specify more elements in CSS: `em, strong { #foobar }` instead of `em { #foobar }; strong { #foobar }`?

Comment: the parser you have addded is a completly performance killer. I suggest you to avoid it 100% time

Comment: @omnosis, even if SASS is written in ruby, it generates *static* CSS files on disk. Thus, there is no need for a PHP script to run for *every* request to generate the exact same CSS, and kill performance. SASS generates the static file for you whenever you change the SASS document, so you can be sure you have the latest compiled CSS on disk, whenever you decide to change something.

Comment: Why the downvotes?! This is a completely valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### LessPhp

Thanks to @Kru I found [**Less.js**](http://lesscss.org/) which is a very nice and clever css parser, but as I said the best solution would be PHP. After a little search on forums and google I found [**LessPhp**](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) which is a PHP port of Less.js

Documentation can be found [here](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/).

LessPhp is also on [github](https://github.com/leafo/lessphp).

Answer (score 5):

Try [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). It supports variables, mathematical computations, style inheritance and many more features. It's not implemented in PHP, but it generates static files.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try [CSS Crush](http://the-echoplex.net/log/css-crush)?

Answer (score 1):

you could include your css with php with:

```
<link href="style.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

In your style.php you do:

```
header("Content-Type: text/css");
```

At this point you can use all the power of php to do what ever you want like:

```
<?php

 $rules = 'font-size:11px;padding:5px;';

?>

td { <?php echo $rules; ?> }
```

### Addedum

Inheritance:

```
<?php

   $parent=array( 'td' => 'color:;padding;etc;'
                  'p' => 'other rules'
                   //> other rules
               );
?>

.inheritance {
    <?php echo $parent['td']; ?>
   //> other rules here
 }
```

Comment: this is not css. this is php.

Comment: what you are asking for **ISN'T** css. you know? And why did you added PHP as tag? I wouldn't have replied with this if you didn't add that tag

Comment: yes that is right, but i dont want to use php variables functions in my "not" css file. i want to use css like stuff, and than parse with php. btw your answer can't solve inheriting problems. i added php tag because the parser should be PHP.

Comment: You don't get the point. You can't use css like stuff because the stuff you want AREN'T css. And of course you can solve the inherthing problem with PHP. You just need to save in a varible the parent rules and then echo the var. I edited my answer to show yuo how.

Comment: you dont understand me. thanks for your answer but this is not what i am searching for. i know that i can modify css with php. but i am searching for a parser.

Comment: @omnosis ok as you wish. next time add more details in your question. And consider this: using a custom parser you will need to learn its syntax, while if you use my solution you can do whatever you want without needing to learn a custom non-standard solution.

Comment: you are right, but as jquery, it is not the features which the browsers give you, but helps you to create a better javascript document, improves developing, saves you time etc... jquery is not a standard solution!

Answer (score 1):

i dont think this is a good idea, esp in a production enviornment, but if you insist on doing this, i would suggest just installing SASS and executing it from php using passthru()

http://sass-lang.com/

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Like this

```
<?php
$css_path = '/';  // location of your real css files
$sass_cmd = 'sass -f';  // sass cmd
passthru($sass_cmd . $css_path . $_GET['cssfile'];
?>
```

called via

```
cssparse.php?cssfile=xyz.css
```

if you want to get fancy you could use a rewrite rule to funnel all your *.css requests thru your PHP script.

eg:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.css$
RewriteRule   ^(.*\.css)$  cssparse.php?cssfile=$1
```

that way when you request /example.css in the browser,
it gets rewritten as /cssparse.php?cssfile=example.css
which calls SASS and returns the output

Comment: thanks, i will check it out as soon as i will have time for that

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do just isn't a good idea. Every time a user loads your CSS file, it first has to go through the PHP function that generates the CSS file from your 'improved' version. It is only needed for, for example, **social networking sites** on which **users can make custom layouts**. Then the custom styles have to be loaded from a database and inserted into the CSS file using PHP.

For website without this functionality, after the CSS is parsed, there is no difference. Creating the CSS file had only been easier/more efficient for you.

Also, if your CSS has to go through a PHP parser, it is not possible to modify the CSS offline.

Comment: I think you better don't waste time on finding a script that does this for you. I personally would do everything to speed up my CSS. And I think a fast website is more important than how easy it is for the designer to make the CSS.

Comment: You are right, but if php generates the css, i can save it with a simple request. Just for developing it would be great.

Comment: You can also remove the parser from your website after you generated the final version of the CSS file.

Comment: ofc. this is not aboute the php, but with php i dont need to open the "parser" program and then save and then load the page. php does it automatically.